# Неожиданный результат при неявном приобразовании INT в CHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть простой запрос:

```
DECLARE
      @Text CHAR (3),
      @Val INT;
SELECT
      @Val = 1000;
SELECT
      @Text = @Val;
SELECT
      @Text;
```

Но его результат удивляет. Почему так?

Comment: Чем удивляет-то? ну не лезет оно в три символа...\

Comment: @Akina тем что результат не "100".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Такое поведение в явном виде описано в документации:
[Truncating and rounding results](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#truncating-and-rounding-results)

> Преобразования в двоичные, char, nchar, nvarchar, varbinary или
>   varchar усекаются, за исключением преобразований, показанных в
>   таблице.
>
> **int, smallint, or tinyint** |   char | *